# Speechrecognition while filming with camera

Tags: java, android, camera, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm developing an android app that needs to film and use speechrecognition at the same time. The problem is, that the camera uses the microphone so the speechrecognition api wont have acces to the microphone.

My solution was to disable the audio in the camera and only record the video. Problem with this solution is that when using the  `RecognitionListener` you can't acces the audio file.

Then i tried to use the `RecognizerIntent` with `startActivityForResult`. The problem with this solution is that the activity will open a 'pop up' and the camera stops working. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you record video. did you receive any callback for what is recording? I mean if you can receive audio, you can save that audio alone, and then access it by recognizer

Comment: Uh huh. I think that was the only option. Unless you find the way to pass the audio data you receive by callback to your recognizer in real time, it will save your time.